# How to create comma separated css declarations with SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm using Bootstrap and SASS to create some coloured ribbons based on Bootstrap theme, using.

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
    .ribbon-#{$color} {
        background: theme-color("#{$color}");
    }
}
```

Generates

```
.ribbon-primary{
   background: my primary colour
}
.ribbon-secondary{
   background: my secondary colour
}
etc etc
```

But I have some CSS properties to apply to all, eg:

```
.ribbon-primary, .ribbon-secondary...{
    display: flex;
}
```

How do I write that in SASS without repeating it for each theme colour delcaration?

Comment: You could use a separate class that sets the common properties, for example `.ribbon` class that has common styles for all the ribbon elements.

Comment: Yes - I am trying to avoid bloating classes too though! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use @extend. This will exactly suit your use case.
This:

```css
%secretClassToBeExtended {
  display: flex;
}

@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
    .ribbon-#{$color} {
        @extend %secretClassToBeExtended;
        background: theme-color("#{$color}");
    }
}
```

Will generate to:

```css
.ribbon-primary, .ribbon-secondary {
   display: flex;
}

.ribbon-primary{
   background: my primary colour
}

.ribbon-secondary{
   background: my secondary colour
}
```